# Should I declare field volatile?

Tags: java, concurrency, reference, volatile

Consider following code:

```
class Foo {
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

    void doAction() {
        ...
        timer.schedule(new SomeTimerTask(), 0L);
        ...
    }

    void cancelAction() {
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Methods are called from different threads. Method doAction() is called first.

Should I declare `timer` field `volatile` to be visible for another thread?

Answer (score 6):

Its better you use `synchronized` keywords on the methods like `doAction()` and `cacelAction()` that **manipulates the crucial state of instance variable** `timer`..

`volatile` keyword acts pretty much as you described for reflecting the volatile field to each thread, but that **only applies to each seperate operation, not to all the operations collectively.**

Comment: @RuslanZagirov Volatile gives simultaneous access to the threads, without engaging into any locking, but synchronize keyword locks the resource by gaining the lock on the object... Now No other thread can get access to this resource, until and unless the thread which has gained the object lock, releases it...at that time another thread gets the lock...now here this thread see the value of the field which was altered by the previous thread.....

Comment: But in this case, the operations on the timer don't need to be executed in a `synchronized` block, because the javadoc states that they are thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to make the field volatile, because neither thread makes changes to the field itself: its value is set once in the initializer, and it does not change after that.

You may need to add synchronization to your methods, but declaring the variable `volatile` is entirely unnecessary in this case: using `final` would be a lot more appropriate.

Comment: As I understand, any field should be declare volatile if propagating its updates for other threads is required. Without volatile keyword, objects fields are visible for all threads interacting with the object, but some thread may cache field value locally. Correct?

Comment: @RuslanZagirov - Your understanding is incorrect in that `volatile` is NOT the only way to do this.

Comment: @RuslanZagirov Even if the value of `timer` is cached locally, all copies of local caches will "point" to the same instance of `Timer` object; because the value does not change, it is OK to cache the reference once and never touch it again.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Not true, see JLS example 17.5-1 ... on the page linked in my Answer.  You MUST either declare the field as `final` or `volatile` or access it from within a synchronized block, etc.  Even if the field is never changed after initialization.

Comment: @StephenC This makes sense - in this case, using `final` is a much better fit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Timer class is thread-safe according to its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html),

Therefore, declaring `timer` to be `volatile` is sufficient.

However, if `timer` is not assigned to anywhere else (as appears to be the case), a *better solution* is to declare the field as `final`.  That is sufficient to ensure that the `timer` variable can be safely used from multiple threads without any further synchronization.  (This is specifically guaranteed by [JLS Section 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).)

If Timer had not been thread-safe, then you would need to do all actions on the Timer instance in a synchronized method or block (or the equivalent implemented using Locks, etc).  Declaring `timer` to be `volatile` or `final` would NOT be sufficient.

Comment: If we update timer field from one thread, volatile field is required for propagating update for other threads. By default when not updated, exact field value is available for all threads. Correct?

Comment: Not correct.  It is NOT the only way to do it ... even if `timer` is updated.  (4 out of 5 answers state this explicitly, and the 5th doesn't contradict it!)

Comment: +1 I checked Timer code and `schedule()` and `cancel()` method are synchronized so there is no point adding external synchronzation.

Answer (score 0):

Even without declaring the field as volatile, it will be visible to all the threads. The `volatile` keyword associated with a variable will instruct the java runtime that this variable will be potentially modified by multiple threads and so should not be cached locally.

Answer (score 0):

Not required to make the field as `volatile` but better to use `synchronized` methods.

```
public void synchronized doAction(){}

public void synchronized cancelAction(){}
```